# how to edit CSV file on python for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, csv, dataset

I have a CSV file dataset for sentiment analysis.
the file is organized in a way that the first column is the index, the second column is 'sentiment' label and the third is 'sentiment-text'.

```
  , Sentiment   ,SentimentText
0 ,      0          "...."
1 ,      1          "...."
2 ,      0          "...."
```

I want to edit this file so that all the sentences with a label 0 will come after all sentences with label 1.
how can I do that with python?

Answer (score 0):

First load you csv file into Python as a Dataframe object using pandas, and make sure that the first column of the file is taken as the index, not as a column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', index_col=0)
```

Then to sort your column along the 'Sentiment column', use the method .sort_values() :

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Sentiment'], ascending=False)
```

More information: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html